# How do update a scheduled quartz Job?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

Both of the below snippets give this error:

> org.quartz.SchedulerException: Jobs added with no trigger must be
>   durable.

```
  JobDetail job = scheduler.getJobDetail(jobKey(jobInfo));
  job.getJobDataMap().put(JOB_CONTENT, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jobInfo));
  scheduler.addJob(job, true);


  JobDetail job = JobBuilder
        .newJob(MyJob.class)
        .usingJobData(JOB_CONTENT, objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jobInfo))
        .withIdentity(jobKey(jobInfo))
        .build();
  scheduler.addJob(job, true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`addJob()` is for adding jobs with no triggers attached: if that is what you want, just add a call to [`storeDurably()`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/JobBuilder.html#storeDurably()) to the JobBuilder; if, as I can only guess, you want to otherwise update the job while retaining the old trigger, you will need to retrieve the existing trigger first, then, if the trigger will not need changes, `scheduler.scheduleJob(newJob, oldTrigger)`; otherwise get a builder for it using [`TriggerBuilder.getTriggerBuilder();`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.7/org/quartz/Trigger.html#getTriggerBuilder()) to build a copy, make your changes, and eventually call `scheduler.scheduleJob(newJob, newTrigger)`.

Comment: For me `scheduleJob()` fails with _Unable to store Job : '...', because one already exists with this identification._

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the job-specific settings, if you are using Spring you should also make sure that your `SchedulerFactoryBean` has `overwriteExistingjobs = true`. Otherwise only the initial trigger/settings of a job will be persisted (if you are persisting them).

Answer (score 2):

With non durable jobs, you must use [`scheduler.addJob(job, true, true)`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/Scheduler.html#addJob(org.quartz.JobDetail,%20boolean,%20boolean)) instead, with 3 parameters. The third parameter tells Quartz to store the job (in RAM) until it gets scheduled, that is until you add a trigger for it:

> `void addJob(JobDetail jobDetail,
>               boolean replace,
>               boolean storeNonDurableWhileAwaitingScheduling)
>               throws SchedulerException`
>
> With the `storeNonDurableWhileAwaitingScheduling` parameter set to `true`, a non-durable job can be stored. Once it is scheduled, it will resume normal non-durable behavior (i.e. be deleted once there are no remaining associated triggers).

Answer (score 0):

This will help to bypass traditional way of updating job.

> 1. Delete *existing job* first using  *scheduler.**deleteJob(jobKey(name,group))***.
> 2. Then Schedule new job using *scheduler.**scheduleJob(jobDetail,trigger,true)***.

surround your code with try/catch(SchedulerEception se)

NOTE: Add this property in quartz properties :) **spring.quartz.overwrite-existing-jobs = true** or else scheduler will add new instance of a job