# Updating a QuartzJob from the running job itself

Tags: spring-boot, quartz

The update of a QuartzJob within a spring boot application works while the job is **not** running ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399946/how-do-update-a-scheduled-quartz-job) or [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/cookbook/UpdateTrigger.html)). The spring variable `spring.quartz.overwrite-existing-jobs: true` is set.

However, when doing the same from within a *running* job the job keeps firing itself in an endless loop without taking into account the interval time (each few milliseconds it fires again). I even tried doing the same from within a TriggerListener but that doesn't change it.

As code example I would have nothing else but what is given in the second link above:

```
// retrieve the trigger
Trigger oldTrigger = sched.getTrigger(triggerKey("oldTrigger", "group1");

// obtain a builder that would produce the trigger
TriggerBuilder tb = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder();

// update the schedule associated with the builder, and build the new trigger
// (other builder methods could be called, to change the trigger in any desired way)
Trigger newTrigger = tb.withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
    .withIntervalInSeconds(10)
    .withRepeatCount(10)
    .build();

sched.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);
```

Did anyone try that from within a running job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works with the following trigger. It is the startAt which makes the difference. Without that the trigger fires immediately again.

```
Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
.withIdentity(triggerName, groupname)
.startAt(Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().plusSeconds(intervalInSeconds).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()))
.withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule()
    .withIntervalInSeconds(intervalInSeconds)
    .repeatForever()
    .withMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires())
    .build();
```